# Split the string using tags using RegEx

Tags: regex

I need help in splitting the below multi tagged string with the tags like `<eyn>` and `<un>` and `<an>`

```
Your colleague <eyn id='test@test.com'>user</eyn> is now communicating with <un id='test@test.com'>user</un> from <an id='4442729'>test, Inc.</an>
```

Comment: Regex for this is far from easy, next to impossible. Use a html/xml parser.

Comment: can't we parse it using RegEx? I know we can parse it for one tag..but need the same for multi tag

Comment: I do not know about "we can", but I know about "I would not, though I probably could for contained special cases". It is just not worth the hassle.

Comment: If you want help with doing this with regex, then add many more examples of the input you want to parse (you will have to take care to see the special cases) and tag the regex flavor you use and the language you are otherwise using and explain in which way you need the parts afterwards. You already got three downvotes and one closevote ("unclear what you are asking"), so it is time to spend some effort on adding useful information.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

## Doing it with Regex

It's not advisable to use a regex to parse HTML due to all the possible obscure edge cases that can crop up, but it seems that you have some control over the HTML so you should able to avoid many of the edge cases the [regex police](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) cry about.

## Proposed Solution

I'd probably want to collect the entire tag, the ID value, and the raw text between the open and close tags all in one action.

**This Regex**

`<(eyn|un|an)\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\bid=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"\s>]*))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?\/?>(.*?)<\/\w+>`

[image]
<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

**Will do the following**

- find all the `eyn`, `un`, `an` tags
- requires the tag to have an ID attribute
- allow the ID attribute value to be unquoted or surrounded by `'` or `"`
- avoids difficult edge cases that makes pattern matching in HTML difficult
- Creates the following capture groups

  - group 0 the entire tag from open to close
  - group 1 the tag name
  - group 2 the ID value
  - group 3 the raw text inside between the open and close tags

## Examples

See also [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/BypvVf/4)

**Sample Text**

Note the difficult edge cases nested inside the second block of text.

```
Your colleague <eyn id='test@test.com'>user</eyn> is now communicating with <un id='test@test.com'>user</un> from <an id='4442729'>test, Inc.</an>

Your colleague <eyn onmouseover=' if ( 3 > a ) { var 
string=" <eyn id=NotTheDroidYouAreLookingFor>R2D2</eyn>; "; } '
  id='DesiredDroids'>This is the droid I'm looking for</eyn> is now communicating with <un id="test@test.com">user</un> from <an id=4442729>test, Inc.</an>
```

**Sample Matches**

```
Match 1
Full match  15-49   `<eyn id='test@test.com'>user</eyn>`
Group 1.    16-19   `eyn`
Group 2.    23-38   `'test@test.com'`
Group 3.    39-43   `user`

Match 2
Full match  76-108  `<un id='test@test.com'>user</un>`
Group 1.    77-79   `un`
Group 2.    83-98   `'test@test.com'`
Group 3.    99-103  `user`

Match 3
Full match  114-146 `<an id='4442729'>test, Inc.</an>`
Group 1.    115-117 `an`
Group 2.    121-130 `'4442729'`
Group 3.    131-141 `test, Inc.`

Match 4
Full match  163-326 `<eyn onmouseover=' if ( 3 > a ) { var 
string=" <eyn id=NotTheDroidYouAreLookingFor>R2D2</eyn>; "; } '
  id='DesiredDroids'>This is the droid I'm looking for</eyn>`
Group 1.    164-167 `eyn`
Group 2.    271-286 `'DesiredDroids'`
Group 3.    287-320 `This is the droid I'm looking for`

Match 5
Full match  353-385 `<un id="test@test.com">user</un>`
Group 1.    354-356 `un`
Group 2.    360-375 `"test@test.com"`
Group 3.    376-380 `user`

Match 6
Full match  391-421 `<an id=4442729>test, Inc.</an>`
Group 1.    392-394 `an`
Group 2.    398-411 `4442729`
Group 3.    406-416 `test, Inc.`
```

## Explained

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    eyn                      'eyn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    un                       'un'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    an                       'an'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    id=                      'id='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"\s>]*                any character except: ''', '"',
                               whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "),
                               '>' (0 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
```